# Can i limit the number of concurrent users playing a video?

Tags: web-part, administration, video

I would like to know if it's possible to limit the number of users who can play a video using the video web part in SharePoint 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible out of the box with SharePoint web part.But you could think of some customization.